# Application Settings vs Property Settings

Tags: .net, visual-studio, settings

What is the difference between file settings.settings in the root of my project(with app.config) and the Seetings.settings in the Properties folder.
I have observed that both files merge after build in the application config file.

Where should I use?

Thanks.

Comment: What type of application are you building? It's not true, in the general case, that property settings are merged into the application configuration file.

Comment: it's a basic desktop window application. I dont know why, but it happens...

Comment: My projects only have a Settings.settings file in the Properties folder.  Did you manually add the one in the project root folder?

Comment: I dont know, It was here when I arrived, it is a 'legacy project'... But it is probably was added. Do you recommend delete it?

Comment: Is it in source control?  If so, I would delete it, you can always roll back if bad things happen.  If it is not in source control, I would probably still delete it after making a backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings from the .settings file will be added to the app.config `<applicationSettings>` element **but not the opposite**.

can be used to store keys and values easily. just put `<add>` element there, write key and value and you're good to go (and you can read them with `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["bla"]`)
BUT, when you put values there you **don't have** type safety and it can becomes really really messy if you always add configurations elements to there.

When you use application settings files (that behind the scenes generates  section in your app.config with sub-section for each settings file) you can enjoy the benefits of types safety and it's more organized in your code.
In addition, it's easier to edit them in runtime (you can have Application scope and User scope).

Hope this helps.